# How to solve Android screen size for different mobile devices?

Tags: android, widget, screen, device

I am testing the Android application in a small screen mobile.  If I use Samsung tablets like other landscape mobile to test my android application the contents are moved slightly.  How do I solve the screen resolution in Android?

Comment: I think you should better check it in the Developer's website, where you have all the information. Here it is [Supporting Multiple Screens In Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 3):

use this in manifest.xml

```
 <supports-screens 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create multiple layouts as per screen size (four different screen size) & put them in different folders under res like below

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation
```

Also you need to add below lines in menifest file

```
<supports-screens 
   android:resizeable="true" 
   android:smallScreens="false" 
   android:normalScreens="true" 
   android:largeScreens="true" 
   android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

For more information [check this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to hardcode things in terms of px. Try using fill_parent wrap_content. Under very necessary circumstances,create separate folders for your layout as in layout,layout-land,layout-small,layout-small-land,layout-large etc. Place your layout in these folders and change your layout settings. Rest will be taken care by Android OS.

Comment: if i put different layout(large,small.medium) in separate folder.how android will handle these layout.is there any changes in manifest file

Comment: add Nagarjuna Reddy's tag in your manifest. Then on changing the orientation or handling different phones, android OS will take care of this itself.

Answer (score -1):

I think you shuold get the screen resoloution in using java code and then set the widgets size by dynamically in `oncreate()` method of `activity` by using the given resolution.